# Excel VBA SQL multiple where condition

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I need help fixing my conditions. I have 3 columns (Case #, Analyst & Status). I need to display a certain Analyst plus all status that aren't closed.

```
Dim c As String
Dim use As String
use = LabelUser.Caption
c = "Closed"

SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Raw WHERE Analyst = '" & use & "' OR Status <> '" & c & "'"
```

this statement displays all cases under the analyst, including closed (c).

I tried this but it displays nothing.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Raw WHERE Analyst = '" & use & "' AND Status <> '" & c & "'"
```

Comment: Have you checked your data to confirm that there should be some results?

Comment: Have you compared your VBA `SQL` query against a manually created query? Are they *exactly* the same query string? Does the query manually return some records?

Comment: i actually added `Status <> ' ' ` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since this question has been made, however, it still worth answering.
Whenever you use SQL statement within ADO connection, you must assign brackets around and dollar sign at the end of the Table's name. E.g: "SELECT * FROM **[tbl_Raw$]** WHERE Analyst = '" & use & "' OR Status <> '" & c & "'"

Comment: Adjustment: After the "FROM" keyword, it's needed to assign the sheet's name not the table's name. So, it's recommended to have only one table within the stated sheet. In this case, the query statement would be: E.g.: "SELECT * FROM [SheetsName$] WHERE Analyst = '" & use & "' OR Status <> '" & c & "'"